# Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52425/bEbT8kEcqnY=/ws

Tags: android, flutter, dart, vscode-debugger, developer-tools

I have the following error in VS Code when I try to run a Flutter project:

[image]

`Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52425/bEbT8kEcqnY=/ws`

I have already tried the following trials but noting fixed the error:

- restart
- reopen project
- created new project

Comment: deleted emulator & created new 
upgraded flutter
i tried every thing i know 
please anyone help me????

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error. It is known as "DevTools".

The DevTools is a suite of performance and profiling tools that run in a browser.

For the debugging & profiling apps, DevTools might be the first tool you reach for. DevTools runs in a browser and supports a variety of features:

1. source-level debugger
2. widget inspector that displays a visual widget tree, and “widget select” mode where you select a widget in the app and it drills down to that widget in the tree
3. memory profiler
4. timeline view that supports tracing, and importing and exporting trace information
5. logging view

In the provided case, if you paste "127.0.0.1:52425/bEbT8kEcqnY=/ws" to your browser while the app is running, you can see the performance and profiling tool named DevTools.

For more information, kindly visit: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/debugging